# Meaning of this statement

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

Some Person has told me this following statement:

> Stop making issues where they already are resting.

Comment: Possibly a reference to "let the sleeping dog lie", meaning that if nothing is happening, there is no sense to disturb the peace.

Comment: I wonder who said it.

Comment: It was by owner of my prev company

Comment: I'm curious, which dialect of English did he use? -- I mean, *issues are resting* sounds a little weird to me in standard English. (It has its own charm, though.)

Comment: He follows US English :)

Comment: @KaranGandhi Interesting. Should I understand that "issues are resting" is really used in US English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means - don't unnecessarily touch the topic when everything is smooth and calm.

[Stop making issues](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issue) - giving unnecessary importance to something (here some topic) or argue about it.

they *(issues)* are already resting  - they are okay, calm and not on the rage.

So, as Victor says, [let the sleeping dog lie](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+sleeping+dogs+lie). Don't invite trouble!

---

As you are an Indian, so the speaker is advising that you should not do something like आ बैल मुजे मार!

Comment: I'm curious: is the sentence standard Indian English, or a literal translation from an Indian language -- or both?!

Comment: No, it's not standard InE. But people try to 'literally' translate Indian proverbs. Even I don't understand that if something is ***resting***, how can it be an ***issue*** at first! @StoneyB I keep on correcting people around me and never get tired! :)